# Compare two hashes with customize rules

Tags: ruby, string, hash, comparison

I need to compare queries in HTTP URL. Here's a typical query:

```
a1 = "name=blabla&id=123456"
```

The query may have variables, e.g:

```
a2 = "name=blabla&id={CustomID}"
```

`blur_compare(a1, a2)` should be `true`. Here are other situations:

```
a3 = "height=170&sex=male"
a4 = "name=blabla"
a5 = "name=blabla&id=654321"
a6 = "id={CustomeID}&name={CustomeName}"

blur_compare(a3, a2) #=> false, params doesn't match.
blur_compare(a4, a2) #=> false, param's number doesn't match.
blur_compare(a5, a1) #=> false, the id doesn't match.
blur_compare(a6, a2) #=> true. order doesn't matter.
```

I was thinking of transfering a string to hash, e.g.

```
{"name" => "blabla", "id" => "123456"}
```

then do the comparison. But my code is messy and long and ugly. Lots of `if`-`else` condition. I'm wondering if there is any better way to do it.

Sorry, here's the codes. Just feel a little shy to share it, especially when it's not well written. But i'm learning :).

path_query.rb

```
class PathQuery

  def self.is_var?(str)
    regex = /^{.*}$/
    str =~ regex ? true : false
  end

  def self.blur_match_query?(query1, query2)
    # deal with the condition when query1 or query2 maybe nil
    if query1 == nil && query2 == nil
      return true
    elsif query1 == nil || query2 == nil
      return false
    else
    end

    res = true
    # return false directly if number of keys is not equal
    if query1.keys.size == query2.keys.size
      query1.each{|k,v|
        # when the value of same key is diff, then need to found out if one of them is variable.
        if v != query2[k]
          if not (PathQuery.is_var?(v) || PathQuery.is_var?(query2[k]))
            res = false
            break
          end
        end
      }
    else
      res = false
    end
    res
  end

end
```

test_path_query.rb

```
class TestPathQuery < Minitest::Test
  def test_blur_match_query?()
    a1 = {"name" => "blabla", "id" => "123456"}
    a2 = {"name" => "blabla", "id" => "{CustomID}"}
    a3 = {"height" => "170", "sex" => "male"}
    a4 = {"name" => "blabla"}
    a5 = {"name" => "blabla", "id" => "654321"}
    a6 = {"id" => "{CustomeID}", "name" => "{CustomeName}"}

    assert_equal true, PathQuery.blur_match_query?(a1, a2)
    assert_equal false, PathQuery.blur_match_query?(a1, a3)
    assert_equal false, PathQuery.blur_match_query?(a4, a2)
    assert_equal false, PathQuery.blur_match_query?(a5, a1)
    assert_equal true, PathQuery.blur_match_query?(a6, a2)
    assert_equal true, PathQuery.blur_match_query?(nil, nil)
    assert_equal false, PathQuery.blur_match_query?(nil, a2)
  end
end
```

Comment: *"I'm wondering is there any better way to do it?"* - better than what? You didn't include any code.

Comment: Is the parsing of the strings the messy thing? Use: `require "cgi"` `CGI.parse "name=blabla&id=123456" # => {"name"=>["blabla"], "id"=>["123456"]}`

Comment: What is `blur_compare`?

Comment: Variables always evaluate to true when matched?

Comment: Doesn't sound too hard or lengthy. If you show us some code, we can provide alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
def self.blur_match_query?(query1, query2)
  (query1.keys-query2.keys).empty?
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise. But we could ignore the values and compare the keys directly only when the value is variable. e.g. `a1 = {"name" => "blabla", "id" => "123456"}`; `a2 = {"name" => "blabla", "id" => "654321"}`, and blur_match_query?(a1, a2) is false in this situation.